# In excel sheet second column data should be validated based on first column.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a requirement to show data as described below.

*First column in the excel sheet is restricted to 3 strings by data validation such as Motorola,Redmi,Oneplus.

*Second column should be restricted with respect to each string of the column1 where 
-Motorola can have 3 values(g2,g4,g5) in column2 ,
-Redmi can have 1 value (note4) in column2,
-Oneplus can have 2 values(oneplus5T, oneplus6) in column2.

I would like to restrict the second column with respect to the value entered in the first column. By entering Motorola in first column, I would like to show a drop down of g2,g4,g5 in second column. For Redmi and Oneplus also I should show their respective models. Since I am unaware of what a user enters in the first column, how to dynamically change the second column content once first column is entered?

I tried using a formula =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(mylist,A2))) > 0 but then I found that this is not what I am looking for.

Please suggest how can I get desired result as described above.

Comment: You need dependent drop downs. Search [tag:excel] for those words.

Comment: Or these are sometimes called 'cascading' I think.

Comment: Yes, cascading list in excel should do the trick. An easy step to step guide is the following [How to create dependent drop list](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/) or this link where there are example files to use as an guide [Dependent list](https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/dependent-drop-lists/)